# Append String array using TextInfo.ListSeparator

Tags: c#, arrays, list-separator

I am reading all lines from a CSV file. I wanted to get the specific line number of the and place it into an array by using **Split**. This is my current way:

```
var resultPath = GetFilePath();
String[] lines = null;
lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(resultPath);
string[] values = lines[result.LineNumber - 1].Split(','); //Get specific line number and place in an array
```

Now, instead of this, I wanted to use `TextInfo.LineSeparator`.

Here is how I attempt:

```
var resultPath = GetFilePath();
String[] lines = null;
lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(resultPath);
var listSeparator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
string[] values = ??? //I am stuck here...
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Look into `String.Join(separatorstring, array)`

Comment: [Why is TextInfo.ListSeparator returned as a string?](//stackoverflow.com/a/17324479)

Comment: As related note, if you're joining lines together, surely your result shouldn't be a string array anymore?

Comment: In code and tags you (correctly) use `ListSeparator`, but in heading and text you talk about a `LineSeparator` (which doesn't exist in `TextInfo`).

Comment: LineSeparator isn't it just `Environment.NewLine` put it after joined each line, btw your result will be string not string array

Comment: Sorry guys, it is TextInfo.ListSeparator

Comment: If I understood correctly, you just want something like `Split(new [] {listSeparator}, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: @Evk, you are the man... Just posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resultPath = GetFilePath();
String[] lines = null;
lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(resultPath);
var listSeparator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
string[] values = lines[result.LineNumber - 1].Split(new String[] { listSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Works Fine Now....

Answer (score 0):

Base on your current way:

```
var resultPath = GetFilePath();
String[] lines = null;
lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(resultPath);
var listSeparator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
string[] values = lines[result.LineNumber - 1].Split(listSeparator); //you can change it directly with your old separator ','
```

Comment: `listSeparator` has type `string`, not `char`. Which overload of `Split` are you attempting to use here?

Comment: It shows listSeparator argument in Split() is invalid